# Growing Array in C

Tags: c

Can any one Explain me plz the concept of Growing Array Of Structs.
i mean dynamic Arrays.
thanks for your Time.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: You need to make sure it gets plenty of sunlight and water it regularly

Comment: I'm sure wiki explains it much better than someone here would care to. Why don't you read it and ask here a specific question?

Comment: Lookup Dynamic Array (like vector, ArrayList) on Wikipedia. That should get you started.

Answer (score 7):

Start with a small array of some size, then whenever you need to increase the size, use [`realloc`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/realloc.html) to do so; it is common to double the size of the array whenever you resize it.

For example:

```
int length = 5;
my_struct *array = NULL;

/* Initialization */
array = (my_struct *)malloc(length * sizeof(my_struct));

/* Use array[0] .. array[length - 1] */

/* When you reach the limit, resize the array */
length *= 2;
array = (my_struct *)realloc(array, length * sizeof(my_struct));
```

Comment: +1 for complete answer, but is that realloc() portable? I mean, I tried that too, but sometimes I get an error and sometimes it works. Same conditions, same system, same data.

Comment: @BlackBear: Yes, it's very much portable. What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Resource leak. A sort of. I don't have that source anymore.

Comment: @BlackBear: if you didn't allocate memory for your structs' members, then you really should have any resources left out when you free that pointer.

Comment: In this code, if `realloc` can't allocate enough memory, you have a memory leak. I think take into a temporary variable and check it  before assigning to `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean dynamic size of an array? In that case you must allocate memory fitting for you needs. See `realloc`

Answer (score 1):

I have a dynamically growing string buffer implementation. You can get it from [here](http://varnam-project.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=varnam-project/libvarnam;a=blob_plain;f=varnam-strbuf.c;hb=HEAD). It uses the same `malloc` and `realloc` technique.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `realloc` function from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Look up malloc?